# Using Microsoft Power Automate to post a reply in a Teams message that contains a particular keyword

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate

I have a working Power Automate flow that posts a trimmed version of an (Exchange) email message containing a particular keyword. Sometimes there are further email exchanges that use the same keyword and I would like send those replies to the first message - currently each email with the keyword is sent as their own message, which is a bit spammy and makes it harder to keep track of the overall conversation.

So, how can I (using Power Automate):

1. request all messages from a given channel
2. search the channel messages for the first instance of a keyword
3. extract the message ID
4. Post reply to the message ID

Is the above even possible with the current Power Automate features?

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you please help me understand whether it is about exchange email or about the messages posted in teams in card format?

Comment: The numbered flow is about Teams only. So, I need to find the right Teams channel message that contains a particular keyword and then send a new reply to that message.

Comment: I have managed to build a working solution by pulling all the channel messages with Get Messages, -> Apply To Each -> Condition - Contains "keyword" -> Post Reply to message id of items('Apply_to_each')?[id].

I wonder if there is a more elegant solution - even with only a hundred messages, the apply-each loop easily takes 10+ seconds and will only get slower as time goes by.